# Prettify SNS JSON from Email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to receive an email with CodeBuild results that is readable. I currently have this working with SNS through a CloudWatch Event. When I receive my email, the JSON is not pretty and is hard to read. I am currently sending back the entire event as seen from the Cloudwatch Target Event below: 
[image]

As a note, I am not working for or with the Whitehouse. Just a cheeky name.

The result returns this via an email: 
{"version":"0","id":"555NOTREAL-97-0226-7d76-909ed659f3b1","detail-type":"CodeBuild Build State Change","source":"aws.codebuild",....

Into something like:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id":"555NOTREAL-97-0226-7d76-909ed659f3b1",
  "detail-type":"CodeBuild Build State Change",
  ....
}
```

I would essentially like to prettify this. Is this possible?

Comment: Realistically you'll need another layer to do this as you need to generate HTML email.  I'm assuming that, by default, this JSON is sent as a `text/plain` mime type.  Your best bet would be for something like a Lambda that gets the SNS notification and sends an HTML email.  Nothing in CloudWatch or SNS is going to do this for you.

Comment: @stdunbar That's what I was trying to avoid. Thank you though. Nothing like JSON.stringify(object, null, 2)